# Arduino as ISP: IC swapping

Tags: arduino, atmega, isp

I usually use my Arduino as an ISP programmer.

Let's say I want to program the blink LED code to my ATmega328 with the bootloader already in it.

Can I just program it in the classical way and pull out the chip from the Arduino? Is there any problem doing like this? It sounds easier and quicker.

(I'm talking only about ATmega328 with the bootloader already in it, not ATtiny or other ATmega chips.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes you can.

Longer answer, mostly stating the obvious for those who might need it:

- Evidently one would need an Arduino with a DIP socket and DIP ATmega microcontrollers - while the classic Uno and several other Arduino boards have this, some of the newer ones are SMD-only.
- This won't work with a fresh ATmega MCU, i.e. one without the bootloader - this is of course already addressed in the question
- The microcontroller ICs can be sensitive - both to manhandling while pulling the IC out (pins break), and possible ESD damage if the pins are not handled with care. The ATmega family is pretty hardy though, so ESD is not as big a risk
- If this method of programming is to be done for a bunch of MCUs, it would be better to use a breadboard or ZIF socket, rather than the socket on the Arduino

Answer (score 3):

> Can I just program it in the classical way and pull out the chip from the arduino ?

Sure you can, you place the chip (that already has a bootloader) to the arduino board, program it and then you can pull it out and place it on a breadboard (connecting the supplies and crystal) and it will work fine.

To put it another way, you can get any empty chip like mega88/168, place it on a breadboard, program it once with the arduino bootloader (using an ISP serial programmer) and after that you can use the bootloaded functionality to program the chip on the breadboard.

Comment: That's not exactly the problem (or I don't get your answer). I'm not talking about programming the IC on a breadboard but putting the IC I want to program "on" the arduino.

Comment: @EmmanuelIstace That will not work, the bootloader is in the actual chip so if you use an empty one there is no bootloader

Comment: I mentioned in the question that the chip I'm using are actually pre-programmed with the bootloader.

Comment: @EmmanuelIstace Then my original reply applies. You can program the chip on the arduino board and then pull it out, place it on a breadboard and use it to execute the code.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry, I re-read it and I don't get your answer the first time. (English's not my native language) I thought you were talking about programming it from the breadboard and then putting it on the arduino.  Thanks for the answer !

Comment: @alexan_e - Sorry about the hassle over the power supply question. Again, sorry if I seemed to be "on your case". but this is a dangerous area and one that many beginners do not seem to take seriously enough. Cheap, easy, low parts count - what's not to like ? :-) :-(. I just looked at the app note. Fig 1 has the Vout at live/phase potential always - doesn't even need a component failure or Murphy at work. Despite their warnings Microchip are most remiss in doing that. Again again - sorry/thanks. RM.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon You caught me off guard and I though there was something wrong with this reply too (!) but then I realized that this was just a way to communicate (I miss PMs of other platforms). In any case I think I will avoid including any non isolated supply material in future replies. And don't worry, your comments were gladly accepted, they had a very positive spirit.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from wearing out the socket, there is no "problem" with using that tactic.

In fact, there are several "roll-your-own" Arduino projects which utilizes other ATMega chips besides those commonly used in commercially available Arduino boards.

[Build Your Own Arduino Compatible Board](https://www.sparkfun.com/news/687)

[How to roll your own programmable Arduino/AVR board](http://flyingcarsandstuff.com/2013/11/how-to-roll-your-own-programmable-arduinoavr-board/)

[Building an Arduino on a Breadboard](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an [FTDI cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DJBNDHE) or [FTDI breakout board](http://www.adafruit.com/products/284) (2 examples linked) so you can program your chip right on the breadboard or in-circuit. Including four more header pins (for Vcc, Gnd, RxD, TxD) on your board makes it quick to connect the FTDI cable.